# Are all Play Framework 2 actions async?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Are all actions in Play Framework 2 async? Or do I have to use Promises deliberately to achieve this?

To clarify, is the IO (NIO) performed on a different thread than the actual action logic?

Comment: What I'm about so say is a _very_ simplified view, so take it as such (but I hope you'll get the gist): Nope, your actions are not async. Well, not automatically. The thing about play bragging to be async and such is that you can just return [`AsyncResult`s](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.AsyncResult), which [you can create easily](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaAsync]. Same thing with everything else. it _is_ not async, it just gives you the tools to easily use async stuff.

Comment: Also Play's Promises are [to be discarded for `scala.concurrent.Future`s](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Highlights).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by *asynchronous*.

All Play actions are non-blocking in the sense that the IO thread that accepts the HTTP request is not the same as the one that runs the action, and never blocks waiting the action to complete. So yes, (HTTP) IO are performed on a different thread than the actual action logic.

Though, the actions themselves can contain computations that may take a while. Thus they may block the thread they are executed in. That's often the case when you perform database operations, because most database drivers are blocking.

Comment: So what exactly is the benefit of performing the main task in another thread using a Promise (or Future)? Compared to having "enough" threads for the actions?

Answer (score 2):

To add to Stephane's answer,

> To clarify, is the IO (NIO) performed on a different thread than the
>   actual action logic

Yes it is